# add app to Google store using external payment processin

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm selling a desktop software and now i want to offer a mobile app which require username and password to login as a bonus for my customers.
I was wondering if i can offer the mobile app on google store for free or do i need a google merchant account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to publish the app on Google Play, you must have a Developer Account and pay a one-time fee, and release the app for free afterwards:
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html

You only need a Google merchant account if you are going to be selling virtual assets through your app. If you aren't selling anything through your app, then you do not need a merchant account. If you plan on selling physical items through your app, then you will need to look elsewhere. [The Amazon Appstore](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/android) allows you to sell physical goods through your app.

So to answer your question, if you aren't selling anything through your app, then no, you do not need a merchant account.